# I am trying to take input from the user and transferring that to a text file

Tags: java

I am trying to code a chatbot that learns the answer from the user, in order to do that I need to save the answers to a text file which later will be read. In the code it allows me to write the question then does not create the text file and gives an error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks All help appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Question[]=new String[10000];
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Lets talk");
    ;

    try {
    for(int i = 1; i<10000;i++) {
        Question[i]=a.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Human: "+ Question[i]);
        x.format("%s",Question[i]); 
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Hmm, an error you must have");
    }

    }
}
```

I want the code to create the text file which has the string that the user has put in and will also allows additional strings to be added

Comment: where is the code which is responsible for creating the file ? `x.format("%s",Question[i]);` Where is the declaration of `x` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PrintWriter.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
        pw.println("Hello world!");
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

If the file `"output.txt"` exists, then the text `"Hello World"` will be in the file.

Here is a link to the Java Docs regarding PrintWriter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) - you can see the official java documentation.

A good example of BufferedWriter is found here - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

I am also curious where your initialization of the x variable is?